# Angular JS ng-repeat Can't getting Output with PHP array

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, angularjs

I am new in Angular JS and I want to display a php array in ng-repeat.
here is my html code,

```
<div ng-controller="clientList">
 <ul>
   <li ng-repeat="client in clients">
    <h2>{{client.job}}</h2>
   </li>
 </ul>
 <p>Total number of phones: {{clients.length}}</p>
</div>
```

Here is my Controller of Angular JS,

```
var anguApp = angular.module('anguApp', []);

anguApp.controller('clientList',function($scope,$http)
{

   $scope.clients=[];

   $http.get('customers.php').success(function (data, status) {
    $scope.clients = data;
    console.log(data);
   });
});
```

customers.php

```
<?php
$arr=['name'=>'David','job'=>'developer'];
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Console Log : 
[image]
getting response in console finely. but not getting in browser. where is the error ?....

Comment: can you attach your console.log(data) result here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its looks like you are requesting an array with no objects from your server. try this in your html code:

```
<li ng-repeat="client in clients">
    <h2>{{client}}</h2>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Gubkin, getting output finely. But how can i print a specific value with key.

Comment: you can't... you are getting an array from your server like this: ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']. your php array need to look something like this: [{name: david}, {name: john}] so you can repeat it by key

Comment: from my little knowledge of php, try this: $named_array = array(
    "nome_array" => array(
        array(
            "foo" => "bar"
        ),
        array(
            "foo" => "baz"
        )
    )
);

Comment: Not getting output.   :(

Comment: hmm. not too experiened with php. maybe try like your array to be like this?: [{"name": 'john'}, {'name': 'david'}]. not sure if this will work, anyway just google it shouldn't be too difficult

Comment: awesome, getting output with echo json_encode([$arr]); Thanks a lot Gubkin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72590/discussion-between-jishad-p-and-matan-gubkin).